# Including JavaScript in PHP's json_encode()

Tags: javascript, php, json

I need to generate the following script using PHP and json_encode().

```
var obj= {
    o1:123,
    o2: {
        o3: 456,
        o4: function() {return $( "#myID" ).val();}
    }
}
```

My attempt to do so is as follows.

```
<?php
$a=array(
    'o1'=>123,
    'o2'=>array(
        'o3'=>456,
        'o4'=>'function() {return $( "#myID" ).val();}'
    )
);
$json=json_encode($a);
?>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    <?php echo("var obj={$json};");?>
    console.log(obj);
</script>
```

The resultant output is as follows.  The quotes around the properties poses no issues, however, the quotes around the JavaScript renders it as a string and not JavaScript.  I obviously can't not quote the JavaScript in the array as it will result in malformed JSON.

How can I include JavaScript in PHP's json_encode()?

```
var obj={
    "o1":123,
    "o2":{
        "o3":456,
        "o4":"function() {return $( \"#username\" ).val();}"
    }
};
```

Comment: You won't be able to generate a JavaScript object with json_encode because a JSON is not the same a JavaScript object.

Comment: @DaveChen.  Is it possible to create the appropriate text for a JavaScript object using any built in PHP function which takes its input from an array or object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about removing the quotations that surround the function?

```
<?php

$obj = array(
    'o1' => 123,
    'o2' => array(
        'o3' => 456,
        'o4' => 'function() {return $( "#myID" ).val();}',
        'o5' => 'function(param) {return $( "#myID" ).val();}'
    )
);
$json = json_encode($obj);

while ($func = strpos($json, '":"function(')) {
    $json = substr($json, 0, $func + 2) . substr($json, $func + 3);
    while ($quote = strpos($json, '"', $func + 2)) {
        $func = $quote + 1;
        if (substr($json, $quote - 1, 1) == "\\") {
            $json = substr($json, 0, $quote - 1) . substr($json, $quote);
            continue;
        }
        $json = substr($json, 0, $quote) . substr($json, $quote + 1);
        break;
    }
}

echo $json;
```

This checks if the string starts with `function(`, and if it is, removes the double quotes.

[The result is a JSON](https://eval.in/private/aa1f55fa9d97d4) (but can still be used as a JavaScript object):

```
{"o1":123,"o2":{"o3":456,"o4":function() {return $( "#myID" ).val();},"o5":function(param) {return $( "#myID" ).val();}}}
```

Upon setting this object to a variable, you can see that the function registered fine.

[image]

With that, you can still use the same technique you used before:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    <?php echo("var obj={$json};");?>
    console.log(obj);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Dave.  Both your and my solution work perfectly, but I like yours as it doesn't require multiple methods like mine does.

Answer (score 2):

JSON does not support functions. It's a data interchange format. Perhaps you should send some configuration data down and have a function change its behavior on that. Or since you aren't doing it as an AJAX call at this point, just echo it out:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
<?php echo("var obj={$json};");?>
<?php echo("obj.myFunc  = function..."); ?>
console.log(obj);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel.  My actual array which gets converted to JSON is much more complicated, and takes a bit of manipulation to create it.  I am not trying to create JSON, but trying to create an object (will actually be used with the following: http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/).  I've created the array, just can't echo it.  Maybe some elaborate parsing to remove only the quotes for JavaScript in the PHP rendered JSON, but that sounds complicated.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up doing.  Kind of hackish, and I expect Dave's is a better solution, but haven't yet tested it.  I will do so.

```
<?php

class fubar {
    public function json_encode_JS($array)
    {
        $array=$this->_json_encode_JS($array);
        $json=json_encode($array);
        $json=str_replace(array('"%','%"'), '', $json);
        $json=str_replace('\"', '"', $json);
        return $json;
    }
    private function _json_encode_JS($array)
    {
        foreach($array as $key => $value){
            if(is_array($value)){$array[$key]=$this->_json_encode_JS($value);}
            else {
                if(strpos($value, 'function(')===0){
                    $array[$key]='%'.$value.'%';
                }
            }
        }
        return $array;
    }
}

$array=array(
    'o1'=>123,
    'o2'=>'function() {return $("#myID").val();}',
    'o3'=>array(
        'o4'=>456,
        'o5'=>'function() {alert("Hello why don\'t you answer "+$("#myID").val());}'
    )
);

?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    <?php
    $obj=new fubar();
    echo('var obj='.$obj->json_encode_JS($array).';');
    ?>
    console.log(obj);
    obj.o3.o5();
</script>
<input id="myID" name="myID" type="text" value="hello">
```

Comment: I like this method! I have adapted my code to allow for parameters within the function. (Searching for `function(` instead of `function()`) I can see my method isn't far from yours actually. Mine removes the first double quotation at `":"function(`, and removes all the escape characters, then removes the last double quotation that isn't escaped. Whereas, you add a delimiter `%` to any string that starts with `function(`, json_encode, then remove the quotation & delimiter, and then removing all the escape characters. The only issue would be that if you had a string with a quotation...

Comment: it wouldn't work. For example, `array('a' => 'hello " world')`. Other than that, it's pretty much the same thing.